# Make scrollbar of the parent with overflow: auto not appear if the child overflows

Tags: css, sass

I have a parent div with an overflow-y: auto. It contains an arbitrary amount of child divs with text. The desired behaviour is for the scrollbar to appear only if the content overflows in the parent div, and to NOT appear if the content overflows in any of the child divs.

The child divs would always have the overflow as the font I use causes an overflow of white space below/above the font with the desired line height (1.2).

Currently the scrollbar incorrectly appears even when the parent div contains not enough child di>s to overflow due to max height.

The only solution I could think of to achieve the desired behaviour is to set line height to 1.5 (minimum height for the font not to overflow) and reduce the space between the lines of text with the negative margins. However I was wondering if there is a nicer solution? I also tried giving children divs overflow-y: hidden; but that still results in the parent having the scrollbar.

```
.parent {
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
   line-height: 1.2; // I cause an annoying scrollbar to appear in the parent
}
```

```
<div className="parent">
  <div className="child">Text</div>
  <div className="child">Text</div>
  <div className="child">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the overflow of an element is the sum of all its child overflow, so if a child is having an overflow then parent will get affect as well

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif! So CSS has no support for removing certain children from that overflow framework?